# Drag to scroll implementation?

Tags: c, winapi

I am writing a program to view disassembly code, which has further prompted me to write a custom text control. I've got most features I need implemented but just need some finishing touches to complete it.

One of those things is dragging to scroll text.

[image: drag to scroll demo]

Are there any pointers on how to implement this? When I click and drag from any given point in the client rectangle, it stops receiving any messages when the cursor leaves the window (as seen in Spy++). I'm clueless on where to start.

Comment: The standard "EDIT" control already does all this, it is not easy to replace.  Avoid losing the mouse by calling [SetCapture()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setcapture).

Comment: @HansPassant Unfortunately, a standard EDIT control simply isn't suitable for a disassembly view. It is meant to be interactive too, not just pure text.

Comment: When you get button down, call `SetCapture()`, then you will get mouse events even when the mouse is outside of the window.